# Copy argument of static Method

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I have Two classes, First the ViewDatabase.java with the following method:

```
public void collectUserInfo(final ArrayList<String> ids){
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();
            //Add Some Users to friends...
            ListOfFriendsFragment.showFacebookFriendUI(friends);
        }
    });
}
```

This method is called from the `ListOfFriendsFragment`. Here is the `showFacebookFriendUI` method:

```
public static void showFacebookFriendUI(ArrayList<User> friendsList){
    if(friendsList.size()>0){
        friends=friendsList; //This is wrong
    }else
        Log.e("ERROR", "No friends");
}
```

The problem is because of the static method I can't use the ArrayList in my fragment. I also can't do the code inside the method because I need to access to some Attributes.
So I just need to get a copy of the ArrayList and use it in the class.

**I can't just return the ArrayList because the getFriends is asynchronus so I need that the showFacebookFriendUI get called when it is finished.

Comment: You need to describe what you're actually trying to do, your current question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword and you'll be able to access `friends`.

Comment: I copy all the Method that I needed inside th ListOfFriendsFragment and it works nicely.